# Use WinJS.xhr to PUT a file to a rest service

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

Real simple task. I have a url to a file in the Win8 client app which I got from doing something like this:

```
this.image = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

and now I need to send the file over the internet kind of like this:

```
var options = {
type: method,
url: MyApplication.servicesUri + "rest/" + dpName + queryParameters,
headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
data: JSON.stringify(objParameters)
};
WinJS.xhr(options)
```

So the thing is, how do I 'reverse' my first operation and get the file so I can set it as the `data` of my PUT request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue with a different approach, but the answer to this question comes from the [DataRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208119). Take a look at the example on the msdn page.

Answer (score 2):

I hit here looking for way to get back StorageFile from the URL, which was created by the call URL.CreateObjectURL(storageFile).

I saw Sebastian thread on [social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/a335ce9a-c838-45d8-b65a-0b2a3aa9fb79) also. could not get anything to work to get back storagefile from URL. I need to use WinJS.xhr() only not background transfer.

I finally used solution to keep both storageFile and URL references - [URL to bind to image.src for display and storageFile for uploading to the blob. [MSApp.CreateFileFromStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh831249.aspx) was useful api for that. full code snippet can been seen [here](http://blog.programtheeworld.com/2013/03/22/uploading-image-to-azure-blob-from-windows-store-app/)

**Update**: I found a way to get the File Object back from the URL returned by URL.CreateObjectURL. This comes from the [w3 File API spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url) section 12.7. Simply use WinJS.xhr to get the blob.

```
// url like - blob: <guid>
WinJS.xhr({ url: url, responseType: 'blob' });
}).then(function (req)
{
    var blob = req.response;
}).then(null, function onerror()
{
});
```